# Symfony and jQuery Sortable integration not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, jquery-ui-sortable

I have implemented jquery sortable in twig and when I drag and drop I need to send the updated order via ajax to the symfony controller.

Inside my twig i am using a loop to display the sortable items

```
{% for goals in form.goals %}
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="item-{{ goals.id.vars.value }}">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2" >
                <label class="" for="exampleInputEmail2">Goal</label>

                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    {{ form_widget(goals.target, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <label class="" for="exampleInputEmail2">Saved to date</label>

                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    {{ form_widget(goals.reached, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <label class="" for="exampleInputEmail2">Goal deadline</label>

                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    {{ form_widget(goals.deadline, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control dp'}}) }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <label class="" for="exampleInputEmail2">Allocated $</label>

                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    {{ form_widget(goals.allocated, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

This is the AJAX call

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    axis: 'y',
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        var order = $(this).sortable('serialize');
        $.ajax({
            data: order,
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{{ path('goals_ajax') }}'
        });
    }
});
```

The problem I am having is how can I get hold of this `order` array in my controller

I have tried

```
$data = $request->request->get('order');
$data = $request->get('order');
```

But these give me `null`

I am guessing once I have that `order` array I should be able to use the following foreach loop to update the order

```
    foreach ($order as $field => $value) {
        $order = $field;
        $id = $value;
        $goal = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Goals')->find($id);
        $goal->setOrderNo($order);
        $em->persist($goal);
    }
    $em->flush();
```

Any help will really be appreciated.

Comment: What did you get when you do : console.log(order); after var order = $(this).sortable('serialize'); ?

Comment: try to debug with **$request->query** and then use **$request->query->get('key')**